# Is copy constructor called if assignment operator wasn't defined?

Tags: c++

Suppose that the `foo` class does not have an overloaded assignment operator. What happens when an assignment `a = b;` is given for two `foo` objects?
options are:

1. The automatic assignment operator is used
2. The copy constructor

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag it as such if it is.

Comment: I don't really get why you named this question this way.

Comment: I don't think the title suits the question very well

Comment: I think it does. But I also think it's very easy for the OP to find the answer himself simply by writing a program with these properties.

Comment: @Mr Lister When Alessandro wrote that comment 11 mins ago, the title looked very different.

Answer (score 4):

It depends:

```
A a;
//this is not an assignment, it is equivalent to A b(a);
A b = a; //default copy constructor is called

A c;
//assignment
c = a; //default assignment operator is called
```

Comment: IIRC the first isn't assignment even though it uses the `=` character, it's initialization and equivalent to `A b(a);`.

Comment: @delnan yup, that's why I said the copy constructor is called.

Comment: My concern being whether it counts as assignment (as the question only ask about what happens upon assignment with no `operator=` defined).

Comment: It's is not assignment. It's initialization just as you said.

Comment: Indeed. So why even bring it up (except perhaps to say that it isn't assignment even though it may look like assignment), instead of answering "no"? Your current answer seems to imply `A b = a` is one form of assignment that does call the copy constructor.

Comment: @delnan for the sake of completness.

Comment: Then at least state it's not assignment and clarify/remove the "it depends". The current answer is very misleading IMHO.